# how start startActivity in chaquopy

Tags: python, android, kotlin, chaquopy

this code

```py
form java import jclass
Intent = jclass('android.content.Intent')
uri = jclass('android.net.Uri')
intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
intent.setData(uri.parse("tel:" + "505"))
activity.startActivity(intent)
```

---

this error
android.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity. startActivity cannot be applied to (JavaClass, JavaClass): options are void android.app.Activity. startActivity (android.content.Intent), void android. app.Activity.startActivity(android.content.Intent, android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have confused a class with an object of that class. To avoid this, it's a good idea to give classes capitalized names, and objects lower-case names. I see you've done that here with `Intent` and `intent`, but not with `uri`.

However, I don't think this code could be the cause of the given error message. Are you sure you've reinstalled the app since the last time you edited the code? And are you sure that the the stack trace line number refers to this code, and not to a different call to `startActivity`?

Comment: when use kivy import avtivity like this ->from plyer.platforms.android import activity but in chaqoupy how do this....Sorry for not writing well in English

Comment: Can you give a simple example using startActivity

Comment: How you get the activity instance will depend on what context your Python code is running in. If you're writing an activity entirely in Python (which we don't recommend anymore), then it'll be the `self` variable in any of the activity's methods. Or if you're calling this code from Java or Kotlin, then you could pass the activity as an argument.